# How to solve error: failed to run custom build command for `redbpf-probes v2.3.0 (/home/user/redbpf/redbpf-probes)`?

Tags: rust, llvm, ebpf, bpf

I was trying to install redbpf from this source
`git clone --branch llvm14 https://github.com/nbaksalyar/redbpf.git`
I encountered this issue while installing.
Here is the steps I have performed:

```
➜  ~ git clone --branch llvm14 https://github.com/nbaksalyar/redbpf.git
Cloning into 'redbpf'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4690, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (970/970), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (407/407), done.
remote: Total 4690 (delta 605), reused 784 (delta 545), pack-reused 3720
Receiving objects: 100% (4690/4690), 1.15 MiB | 163.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2650/2650), done.
➜  ~ cd redbpf
➜  redbpf git:(llvm14) git submodule sync
➜  redbpf git:(llvm14) git submodule update --init

Submodule 'bpf-sys/libbpf' (https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf.git) registered for path 'bpf-sys/libbpf'
Cloning into '/home/u1tron/redbpf/bpf-sys/libbpf'...
Submodule path 'bpf-sys/libbpf': checked out '56794b31eea0a6245f194b5915e3ed867be144fe'
➜  redbpf git:(llvm14) cargo build
   Compiling libc v0.2.121
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.37
```

This was the error I faced:

```
   Compiling redbpf v2.3.0 (/home/u1tron/redbpf/redbpf)
warning: field is never read: `flags`
   --> redbpf/src/symbols.rs:110:5
    |
110 |     flags: i32,
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default
    = note: `CacheEntry` has a derived impl for the trait `Debug`, but this is intentionally ignored during dead code analysis

warning: `redbpf` (lib) generated 1 warning (1 duplicate)
warning: `redbpf` (lib) generated 1 warning
warning: use of deprecated function `llvm_sys::core::LLVMBuildCall`: Use LLVMBuildCall2 instead to support opaque pointers.
   --> cargo-bpf/src/llvm.rs:126:5
    |
126 |     LLVMBuildCall(builder, exit, ptr::null_mut(), 0, c_str.as_ptr());
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: `#[warn(deprecated)]` on by default

warning: `cargo-bpf` (lib) generated 1 warning (1 duplicate)
   Compiling redbpf-probes v2.3.0 (/home/u1tron/redbpf/redbpf-probes)
warning: `cargo-bpf` (lib) generated 1 warning
   Compiling probes v0.1.0 (/home/u1tron/redbpf/redbpf-tools/probes)
   Compiling redbpf-tools v0.1.0 (/home/u1tron/redbpf/redbpf-tools)
   Compiling example-probes v0.1.0 (/home/u1tron/redbpf/examples/example-probes)
error: failed to run custom build command for `redbpf-probes v2.3.0 (/home/u1tron/redbpf/redbpf-probes)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/u1tron/redbpf/target/debug/build/redbpf-probes-803241f678ed6eea/build-script-build` (signal: 6, SIGABRT: process abort signal)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/bpf_helper_defs.h
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/bpf_helpers.h
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/bpf_iter.h
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/redbpf_helpers.h
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/vmlinux_supplement.h
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/xdp.h
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=KERNEL_SOURCE
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=KERNEL_VERSION
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=REDBPF_VMLINUX
  Aug 18 21:54:13.989 DEBUG build_script_build: Try generating rust bindings with pre-installed kernel headers

  --- stderr
  : CommandLine Error: Option 'use-dbg-addr' registered more than once!
  LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
➜  redbpf git:(llvm14)
```

My OS and Version

```
➜  ~ uname -a
Linux u1tron-arch 5.19.1-arch2-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu, 11 Aug 2022 16:06:13 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

LLVM Version is 14.0.6.
I've been facing this problem for a while. Any help would be much much appreciated.
I have also created this issue on their github: https://github.com/foniod/redbpf/issues/341

Comment: Have you solved this issue? If you did, please self-answer the question as I'm facing the same problem. If not, I'm gonna start a bounty.